# Release memory of std::list<cv::Mat> c++

Tags: c++, list, opencv, memory, free

I want to free the memory of a list container which contains cv::Mat types. I read a lot here and tried the following things, that did NOT work:

```
std::list<Mat> images; // This is a static member object;
```

**swap trick:**

```
std::list<Mat>().swap(images);
```

or

```
std::list<Mat> foo;
foo.swap(images);
```

**erase each Mat:**

```
for (std::list<Mat>::iterator it = images.begin(); it != images.end(); ++it)
{
    it  = images.erase(it);
}
```

**release each Mat:**

```
for (std::list<Mat>::iterator it = images.begin(); it != images.end(); ++it)
{
    it->release();
}
```

**use a std::list* Pointer:**

```
delete std::list<Mat>* images;
images = new std::list<Mat>;
```

**free memory of each Mat with free():**

```
for (std::list<Mat>::iterator it = images.begin(); it != images.end(); ++it)
{
    free(&(*it));
}
images.clear();
```

**resize list:**

```
images.resize(0);
images.clear();
```

I am not able to create the data in the heap / scope, so it will be deleted when it goes out. It has to be a static member object. A vector is also not suitable for me, because of multiple removals of arbitary Matrices.

Anyone knows what i could do to free the memory?

Comment: You may want to say why you think some of those things aren't working, i.e. what output are you getting that defines the error.

Comment: i don't get any error except for the part with free(). This one produces a memory exception. Regarding the others, the memory is just not available after using those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear the list just to  `images.clear()`.

Note that the C++ standard library and the C heap allocator cache memory and do not return it to the OS immediately. You can try `malloc_trim(0)` call to ask the C heap allocator to return the memory to the OS, but it is not required to honour this request.

Comment: but .clear(); does not free the memory, does it? I think it just sets the size to 0 but the memory stays allocated

Comment: @Ammy It deallocates the memory allocated for the (internal) list nodes. You may confuse it with `vector::clear` which keeps the allocated array for reuse. Either way, when a container gets destroyed it releases all of its memory.

Comment: malloc_trim(0) dit it! I spent so many hours on this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Regarding the OS memory: Is there a way to tell the OS, that the program needs e. g. 5GB more as it actually does respectively reserve this amount instantly without allocating memory with malloc?

Comment: @Ammy No portable way.

Answer (score 1):

cv::Mat::deallocate() deallocates the matrix data.

Clearing the list might not in every case deallocate the cv::Mat objects, since cv::Mat does reference-count, and in case you have other cv::Mat objects with the same data (or submatrices), they won't be deallocated.

A few remarks:
- I suppose you mean std::list? It is very confusing seeing a list type without knowing which it is. Better not use using namespace at all, but especially not when asking questions.
- While most of the things you do seem harmless enough, the free() call seems very scary. Never use free unless you have a malloc for it, and best avoid it completely in C++, that's what new and delete are for.

Comment: i corrected my question. I only tried free(), because I was running out of possible solutions.